# Is there a way to extend the 10mb file limit for Excel Online file collaboration?

Tags: office-365, office-web-apps

When we need to collaborate on the same Excel sheets in the same time we frequently do it on Excel Online. Today for the first time we bumped into a limit of Office 365 (I guess). It warned us that the file was larger than 10 mb and that we couldn't collaborate on it.

My question is if there's a setting in Office 365 administration which can change this limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are certain size limitation to view excel file in Excel Online with Office 365 subscription. The actual limit is `10MB` as you also know.

***"There is no provision to increase that limit up till now"***

But still Microsoft provide some of the options to deal with such situation. This ways are described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/File-size-limits-for-workbooks-in-SharePoint-Online-9e5bc6f8-018f-415a-b890-5452687b325e).

Some of the way are:

- If you have Excel installed on your device, you can download the workbook and then open it in Excel.
- If you have [edit permissions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Reduce-the-file-size-of-a-workbook-573ac275-6456-46f9-9322-2403414d21c0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to the workbook, you can try to reduce the workbook's file size.

According to me you can try with Second option suggested once.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, No.

`Workbooks` that exceed `10 megabytes (MB)` cannot be viewed in `Excel Online` from within Microsoft SharePoint Online.

To view larger files, you’ll need the Excel desktop app installed on your computer.